# HtmlAgilityPack reading table after specified table

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I have similiar structure to this:

```
<table class="superclass">                    
   <tr>                                                                  
       <td>    
       </td>                                                            
       <td>                                                     
       </td>                                                             
    </tr>                                                                
   <tr>                                                                  
       <td>                                                        
       </td>                                                             
       <td>                                              
       </td>                                                            
    </tr>                                                                
</table>                                                                

<table cellspacing="0">                                                  
    <tr>                                                                 
       <td>                                      
       </td>                                                            
       <td>
       </td>                                                            
    </tr>                                                    
    <tr>                                                                 
       <td>                                                       
       </td>                                                            
        <td>                                                       
       </td>                                                            
    </tr>                                                                
</table>
```

This is how I get the first table with class:

```
HtmlNode firstTable = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class=\"superclass\"]");
```

Then I read the data. However I don't know how to get straight to the another table and read that data too. Any ideas?

I'd rather avoid counting which table it is and then using index to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is XPath `following-sibling` axis which allows you to get element following current context element at the same level :

```
HtmlNode firstTable = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class=\"superclass\"]");
HtmlNode nextTable = firstTable.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::table");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access multiple nodes, you can consider SelectNodes(xpath) method over SelectSingleNode(xpath) method.

I'll provide a sample code here for reference, it may not work towards your need.

```
        var tables = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        foreach (HtmlNode table in tables)
        {
            if (table.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("superclass"))
            {
                //this is the table of class="superclass"
            }
            else
            {
                //this is the other table.
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's cool, however I need something more about reading table which is next to other one. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3703750 if the xpath you have provided allows you to select all tables on this page, then you are essentially iterating over all tables. you need to figure out what criteria helps you identify each table (eg class/cellspacing attribute, or even the order they are selected etc)